# Issues with calculating integral $\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x\sin x}{(x^{2} + a^{2})^{2}} dx$ using residues.

Tags: definite-integrals, complex-integration, residue-calculus

I have this integral $I = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{x\sin x}{(x^{2} + a^{2})^{2}} dx$. I tried to calculate it myself, but apparently I'm using the wrong residues formula, the answer doesn't come out.

$I = \int_{0}^{+\infty} f(z)dz  =\int_{0}^{+\infty} \frac{z\sin z}{(z^{2} + a^{2})^{2}} dz$. Poles: $z^{2} + a^{2} = 0 \to z_{1,2} = \pm ia$ - poles are order $n =4.$

The residue of 4th order is: $\text{Res} f(z_{1,2}) = \lim_{z\to z_{1,2}}(\frac{1}{(3)!})\frac{d^{3}}{dz^{3}}[(z-z_{1,2})^{4}f(z)]$ if I put the rest of the data to that formula I won't get the right answer ( which is $I = \frac{π e^{-a}}{4a}$).

What could be wrong?

Comment: I disagree that the order of the poles are $4$: factorize the denominator

Comment: Also beware that $\sin z$ blows up at *(complex)* infinity. That is, use $e^{iz}$ instead.